# Why does onActivityResult fail to enter method?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have an activity `B` called by an activity `A`.

In activity `A`:

```
intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SelectionActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

In activity `B` (it's about a ListView when items are clicked):

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv = (TextView)arg0.getChildAt(arg2);
                String key = tv.getText().toString();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                myIntent.putExtra("genre", key);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,myIntent);
                finish();
            }
```

And I override the `onActivityResult` method like this in `A`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              if (data != null) {
                 Bundle b = data.getExtras(); 
                 String str = b.getString("genre");
                 Log.v("nope","loaded ! " + str);
                 r.LoadGenre(str);
              }
              Log.v("nope"," not loaded ! ");
           }
        }
```

But I'm never reaching any of these `Log.v` messages.

LogCat is clear, no errors. When running, `A`, it starts `B` perfectly, when items are clicked on `B`, `B` closes perfectly to get back to `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to pass `request code` to the `startActivityForResult()` method.
The  "request code" identifies your request. When you receive the result Intent, the callback provides the same request code so that your app can properly identify the result and determine how to handle it.

In your case you didn't checking received result with `requestcode`

So check `requestCode`  also in your `onActivityResult` method.So Change

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

to

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
```

and

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

to

```
if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

Comment: It's working. Why is this hapenning?
And when you call OnActivityResult, does A call "OnCreate" again? If not, how to make it call ?

Comment: @user3745776 No, on create called only on activity creation,and in OnActivityResult onCreate is not called ,because your activity A in  Activity's stack.